# awk to parse and update file based on condition in field

Tags: awk

In the `awk` below if `$7` or the `Error` field has the words `new` or `update` in it, then the `aaa#number#` is extracted (this is always the pattern), and printed in `$5` or `ID2` and the word `New` is printed in `$6` or `Status` field. If `$7` does not contain either of those words it is skipped and in the input file there are empty fields that may remain in the output.

**data structure**  `tab-delimited`

```
#   xxx     ID   Pos    ID2    Status   Error   Comment
    empty                      empty    empty   empty
```

**file**  `tab-delimited`

```
#,xxx,ID,Pos,ID2,Status,Error,Comment
135,,ABCD1,153740155,,,[Cells: AH8] ....
135,,ACADVL,7222674,,,[Cells: F9-J9] location (1) is inconsistent with (3)
135,,ACP5,11575174,,,"[Cells: D11-T11, AB11-AD11] This record is new and update, submitted aaa000000001 already.,aaa
136,,ACTA2,88943843,,,"[Cells: D12-T12, AB12-AD12] This record is new and update, submitted aaa000000002 already.
136,,ACVRL1,51913357,,,[Cells: F140-J140] location (1) is inconsistent with (3),aaa
```

**desired**  `tab-delimited`

```
#,xxx,ID,Pos,ID2,Status,Error,Comment
135,,ABCD1,153740155,,,[Cells: AH8] ....
135,,ACADVL,7222674,,,[Cells: F9-J9] location (1) is inconsistent with (3)
135,,ACP5,11575174,aaa000000001,New,"[Cells: D11-T11, AB11-AD11] This record is new and update, submitted aaa000000001 already.,aaa
136,,ACTA2,88943843,aaa000000002,New,"[Cells: D12-T12, AB12-AD12] This record is new and update, submitted aaa000000002 already.
136,,ACVRL1,51913357,,,[Cells: F140-J140] location (1) is inconsistent with (3),aaa
```

**awk**

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    FS = "\t";                            
    OFS = "\t";
}
{
    a = patsplit($7, arr, /aaa[0-9]/);    # split $7 variable s and each aaa value into arr
    $7 = arr[1];                          # new $7 value is arr
    for(i = 2; i <= a; i++) {             # start s loop
       $5 = arr[1];                      # new $5 is arr
       $6 = "new";                       # new $6 is new
}
print $0;                             # print new output
}'
```

Comment: This is not valid awk code. Does it comes from ChatGPT or a ugly copy paste from random answer on SO? Looks not a real attempt. Quote conflict

Comment: This is a real attempt from ode I have used before.... all be it not the best....  I will add comments as to my thinking. Thank you :).

Comment: Take at least the time to make it valid awk before submiting, I mean without syntax error. When you will have something better, please, edit your post, no comment with valid `awk`. Il will upvote your question as well

Comment: `NR` means record (or line) number, `NR == 7` (7th record/line number) is not the same as `$7` (7th field)

Comment: Not to mention, `awk` won't work where there are missing fields (there is just nothing for `Error`, so checking by fields won't 'work). You can decorate the text so that each field has something and then use `awk` to evaluate with numeric field numbers. If using `awk` is a requirement -- I'd ask for a file that has all fields present.

Comment: I will make another attempt at this and repost. Thank you :).

Comment: When you post it again I recommend you use comma (or any other visible character) separated instead of tab-separated examples so we can see where the fields start/end as right now with the example in your question we'd just be guessing. You can convert whatever answers you get to tab-separated yourself later. Also, if the block of text under `data structure tab-delimited` is providing any useful information state what that is as it seems to be adding nothing.

Comment: I added a new attempt at the `awk` , added comments, and updated the input to comma separated. Thank you :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should give you the desired result:

run using  `awk -f myscriptfile.awk  myinputfile.txt > myoutput.txt`

```
BEGIN{
  # set variables for input and output separator
  FS="\t"
  OFS = "\t"
}
{  
  # Check criteria: "new" followed by "update"
  # See https://learnbyexample.github.io/learn_gnuawk/regular-expressions.html
  # 
  if (match($7, /new.*update/)){
         # capture the result
         # "aaa" followed by one or more digits
         match($7, /(aaa[0-9]+)/, arr)
         
         # and replace variables as needed
         # if no match leave alone.
         $5 = arr[1]
         $6 = "new"
     }
     
     # output the line
     print $0 
}
```

*Note* As [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) points out, this solution requires [GNU AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) because of `match(what, expression, variable)` construct.  Tested using `GNU Awk 4.2.1` for Windows.

Comment: This could probably be done in a one-liner at command prompt, but I prefer verbose scripts, since it's more readable later on.